# Не знает(,) кого укусить

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

***Не знает(,) кого укусить***.

Можно тут без запятой? Налицо некий фразеологизм, причем ни по интонации, ни по смыслу там ставить эту запятую не хочется. Но достаточно ли этого?

В Сети пишут и так и этак, но авторитетных источников не обнаружил.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение "не знает кого укусить" имеет переносный смысл, и это желательно обозначить отсутствием запятой.

У Розенталя есть самые общие рекомендации на этот счет: в цельном по смыслу выражении запятая не ставится. Например: делайте что хотите, живу где придется.

При этом цельность выражения в одних  случаях очевидна, а в других, менее известных, она требует обозначения, да и цельные выражения могут иметь парные варианты письма в различных текстах, при разных ситуациях.

Поэтому написание без запятой "не знает кого укусить" не противоречит общим правилам.

Можно посмотреть: **Словари и энциклопедии на Академике** [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/253388/не](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/253388/%D0%BD%D0%B5)

**не знать как быть**

ум за разум зашел, **не знать что делать**, растеряться...

**А вот интересное название** у видео (здесь как бы прямое значение выражения): "Бедный пес, не знает кого укусить".  В таком предложении запятую просто некуда ставить, она будет затемнять смысл. http://www.yaplakal.com/forum28/topic1311358.html

Comment: Какой это переносный смысл?! А дальше вы говорите о "цельных по смыслу выражениях" – это что, одно и то же? Если цельность "не очевидна", значит, ее просто нет, и обозначать, стало быть, нечего. Обычный сравнительный оборот.

Comment: Я думаю.что переносный смысл такой: раздраженный человек не знает, на ком выместить свое недовольство, то есть "не знает кого укусить". Оборот в таком значении приобретает цельность, произносится без пауз. Поэтому ставить запятую в нем нежелательно, как и в любом другом цельном по смыслу обороте.

Comment: Откуда только вы это берете...

Comment: К сожалению, в наших правилах очень мало объяснений, а Розенталь рассказал нам очень малую часть того, что знал сам. Поэтому не так просто применять эти правила, приходится их как-то домысливать, отсюда и возникают разные мнения.

Answer (score 0):

> Налицо некий фразеологизм

Никаких фразеологизмов, запятая ставится на общих основаниях. "Авторитетные источники" – справочники.